# Is there in KDB/Q any way to check integrity of a partitioned table?

Tags: kdb, data-integrity, integrity, database-integrity

Is there in KDB/Q any way to check integrity of a partitioned table?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check?  Also look into .Q utilities.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing really out-of-the-box unless you consider some of the newer .Q functions useful (e.g. http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qbv-build-vp)

Aaron Davies has a proof of concept of a "hdb checker" but I'm not sure how complete it is: https://github.com/adavies42/qist/blob/master/lib/hdb_assert.q

Comment: I am looking for a way to check that all the files in are consistent with each other and that content of the table was not modified. For example, by computing some value (MD5, etc) for the table, which would change if the table was accidentally modified in any way. Just computing MD5 for the zip file of the table in not enough since I want to be able to compare the table content at different levels of compression, or after saving the same table with a different method.